# relative path parsing in sftp url with python urllib.parse

Tags: python, parsing, url, sftp, urllib

I have a sftp remote server. I want to use a library that uses the pysftp package to upload files to the server. The relevant source code part is:

```
import pysftp
import os


user = os.getenv("FTP_USER")
pwd = os.getenv("FTP_PWD")
path = "dir"
with pysftp.Connection('192.168.100.120', username=user, password=pwd) as ftp:
   if not ftp.exists(path):
      print("Directory does not exists. Create it")
      ftp.mkdir(path)
   with ftp.cd(path):
      ftp.put('output.txt')
```

It works fine if `path` is relative to the sftp folder and the user has the right to write into it. The problem comes from the parsing of the URL I gave to the library which extracts the path where to store files:

```
from six.moves import urllib 

urllib.parse.urlparse("sftp://user:password@server_ip/path").path
```

which return `/path` instead of `path`, and of course the user has no right to write to the root of the server.

What am I doing wrong in the URL ? How to construct it so that the path is a relative one and not an absolute one ?

Answer (score 0):

URLs like `protocol://...` are absolute.  So if your account is not chrooted, you will have to say:

```
sftp://user:password@example.com/home/user/path
```

---

If you want relative URL, you will have to come up with your own proprietary syntax and process it on your own. E.g. saying that URL like this is relative:

```
sftp://user:password@server_ip/~/path
```

And then if you see that `.path` starts with `/~/` - you drop that prefix.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I use a library that does the parsing with `urllib` so I can't do the parsing by myself

Comment: I do not understand. What library? From your question, it looks like your have a script that gets URL as its configuration, you parse the URL and use URL parts as inputs to your pysftp code. Or is it otherwise?

Comment: I looked at the source code inside the library (MLFlow) which has a module that adds an abstraction layer to upload files to an sftp server. It did not work the way I used it so I tried to find my issue reproducing the problem in the code snippet I provided. The only control I have is on the URL.... or propose a PR to the authors of the library

Comment: OK, so the *"I want to use the pysftp package to upload files to the server"* part is actually irrelevant to your question, right? -- Then you have no other option than to use an absolute path in the URL.

Comment: Your edit still does not explain the link between the URL and the code. The code does not use any URL, it has username/password/path/hostname separate.